# Why django-admin uses POST to change password?

Tags: django-admin, http-method

Checking what response status will I get if I try to change password for a only numeric one I was surprised when I read on the log "[22/Feb/2024 19:25:00] "POST /admin/core/user/3/password/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6115". Shouldn't it use PATCH method as it update only partialy user object?